# How to display the result of a selected form when M-x eval-region is executed in emacs

Tags: emacs

When I execute `M-x` `eval-region` with `(+ 1 1)` selected in  emacs, I can not see the result `2` in the minibuffer . How can I see the result just like `C-x` `C-e`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this function:

```
(defun my-eval-region (start end)
  "Evaluate the region, printing the result to the minibuffer."
  (interactive "r")
  (eval-region start end t))
```